# How much is the markup for ordering items from the Happy Home Showcase?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

So I received a special visitor today to my Happy Home Showcase.

[image: his body is ready]

I know that you can order items from people who have homes in your HHS for a higher price, but it's not stated in-game, in the instruction booklet, on [Nookipedia](http://nookipedia.com/wiki/Happy_Home_Showcase), or on the [Animal Crossing Wikia](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Happy_Home_Showcase) exactly *how much higher* that price is. Reggie does actually have a few items I'm interested in, but I'd like to know how much more I'll have to pay.

How much more do I need to pay for ordering through the HHS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After going through Reggie's house, documenting all the items that he owned that I also had in my catalog, comparing the prices and doing the math, I've found out that ordering an item through the Happy Home Showcase is **1.2x more expensive**.

Here are a few of the items for comparison:

```
Item                  Catalog Price     HHS Price
Modern Wood Stool        1,480           1,776
Dartboard                1,520           1,824
Exotic Screen            2,250           2,700
```

In addition, you can only order up to 5 items in a single day. I was able to find additional sources confirming this number [here](http://bidoofcrossing.tumblr.com/post/49658533547/animal-crossing-new-leaf-happy-home-showcase) and [here](http://acwiki3ds.wikispaces.com/Happy+Home+Showcase), though it's still not stated on [Nintendo's official website](http://animal-crossing.com/newleaf/connect/#showcase) (which is par for the course for a lot of this game).

So if you want to order something, you'll have to pay 20% more bells, but it may be worth it for those items that you really want and/or haven't been able to find yet. Standard limitations on rare items apply here, so anything you can't order normally through your own Catalog, like the Nintendo set, Gyroids, HHA rewards, etc., you also cannot order through the HHS.

Comment: It looks like you have the Exotic Screen prices swapped.

Comment: Oh , So the HHS price is diffrent from catalog price, never notice about that, and it's sad that, sloopy set can't bought from HHS